# Negative binomial distribution mixture model with R

Tags: r, regression, model, negative-binomial-distribution, mixture-distribution

I have two data vectors of observed count data: $A$ and $B$, where count $A_n$ and $B_n$ refer to the same observation point.

$A$ is assumed to follow a negative binomial distribution. $B$ is assumed to be the result from two underlying processes. For one again an independent negative binomial distribution and additionally a kind of shadowing effect from $A$, where a certain fraction $f$ of counts from $A$ are also observed in $B$.

Accordingly, one can simulate such data by:

```
set.seed(13579)
f <- runif(1)
A <- rnbinom(100, mu = 100, size = 1)
B <- floor(f*A) + rnbinom(100, mu = 20, size = 1)
```

**Now to my question: Since $B$ is a mixture model of two negative binomial distributed variables, how can I estimate the value of factor $f$ explaining the underlying data best?**

The final result should be a vector $B^\prime$, correcting $B$ for its shadow portion: $B^\prime = B - (A/f)$. Since I know $A$ and $B$, to gain this I need to estimate $f$ from the data and the underlying assumption of a negative binomial distribution.

I'm neither a statistics nor an R expert, therefore any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I've formatted your post for LATEX. Additionally, I changed B2 to $B^\prime$ for clarity (so that B2 doesn't look like $2B$ or $B_2$). Please check that I did not inadvertently alter your meaning.

Comment: You got my intention perfectly; thanks user777

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?